# How to return array of hashes with modified values

Tags: ruby, enumerate

I've been successfully converting an array of objects into an array of hashes. But I also want to modify the objects slightly as well, before getting the combined hash.

This is what I do to convert array of objects into a combined hash:

```
prev_vars.map(&:to_h).reduce({}, :merge)
{ "b"=>#<Money fractional:400 currency:GBP> }
```

But what I want to have instead, which required to additionally call `to_i` is:

```
{ "b"=> 4 }
```

I got this working using this line, but I am looking for a more elegant solution:

```
prev_vars.map(&:to_h).reduce({}) { |combined, v| combined.merge({v.keys[0] => v.values[0].to_i}) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How large is `prev_vars`? `map(&:to_h)` could require a fair amount of memory overhead, because it instantiates an entirely new array. Instead, I'd recommend switching the order: first `#reduce`, then `#to_h`:

```
prev_vars.reduce({}) do |combined, var|
  combined.merge! var.to_h.transform_values!(&:to_i)
end
```

Note the use of `#merge!` rather than `#merge` so that a new hash is not created for `combined` for each iteration of the loop.